# Change Highlight Color for UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

Is it possible to change the highlight color (shown when the showsTouchWhenHighlighted property is set to `true`) of a UIButton used in a UIToolbar? By default it's white, and since most apps use white images, it isn't the most appealing as the white highlight washes out the image. I would prefer something more like a light gray that really would highlight the image instead of preventing the user from seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, the answer is NO.

Comment: I guess it's really not a huge deal considering the user's finger is placed over the icon while interacting with the button. The issue really only stands out when testing on the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

EmptyStack is right AFAIK, but you could always make your own `UIButton` and use it as a custom view for your `UIBarButtonItem`. A little work, but doable.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, since I want complete control over placement and I'm adding text underneath. How would I go about overriding the color for the highlight?